# Why are there no archives under the organizer section in xcode?

Tags: xcode, archive

I am in the process of uploading my ios app to the app store and I clicked on the organizer button but no archives came up. All that came up was "Use the Archive command within an Xcode project or import an archive from an Xcode Server bot." Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've already created an archive by going to Product > Archive. I would try restarting Xcode. That might not be helpful, but that's where I would start, let me know.

Answer (score 18):

To build your archive you need to:

1 - Set "Generic iOS Device" as the selected device (top left corner near the scheme) instead of a simulator device.

2 - Click on "Product" on the top bar, and then "Archive". This will start building your archive. When it finishes the Organizer will comes up and you will be able to see your archive.

Comment: Woooow, terrible UI design on Apple's part. Took way to long to figure out I had to switch back to Generic iOS Device. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Matias Jurfest answer, in Xcode 12, you would need to

Set "**Any** iOS Device" as the selected device (top left corner near the scheme) instead of a simulator device.